# Does the 2-functor $PsAlg\to \mathfrak{X} $ reflect equivalences?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, 2-categories

Consider a $2$-monad $ T: \mathfrak{X}\to \mathfrak{X} $ and consider its 2-category of pseudoalgebras $PsAlg$. There is a forgetful functor $ U: PsAlg\to \mathfrak{X} $.

Does this forgetful functor reflect equivalences?

I couldn't find any mention of this fact in the literature that I've been reading. But this can be a trivial question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think, no. At least for 1-monads and their algebras: consider for example the monad ${\bf Set}\to {\bf Set}$ of free groups, its algebras are the groups, and there are nonisomorphic groups whose underlying sets are isomorphic (e.g. $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$). I guess, for $2$-monads, the situation is similar..

Comment: Reflecting isomorphy is not the same as reflecting isomorphisms. Any monadic functor (in the ordinary sense) reflects isomorphisms.

Comment: Hermida gives a pseudomonadicity theorem in [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/243788352_Descent_on_2-Fibrations_and_Strongly_2Regular_2Categories) (Theorem A.2), where he says it's easy to show that a pseudomonadic functor reflects equivalences. He also refers to Kelly, _Coherence theorems for lax algebras and for distributive laws_ for a proof, but unfortunately Springer is hiding it behind a paywall. There's also [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902000385) which appears to use reflection of _adjoint_ equivalences.

Comment: it does, though the proof is painful